# Fill the date field (today date) automatically o when you access to a view

Tags: view, odoo

I want to change the value of field ( that changes to the date of the day for example)
automatically or when you access an already created view the action is generate in odoo13.

Thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `fields_view_get` method, it will fired with every type of view, if you need it when a `form` is open you can do something like this:

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(Movimiento, self).fields_view_get(
        view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu
    )
    if view_type == 'form':
        # Get today date
        today = fields.Date.context_today(self)
        # update your field here. 
    return res
```

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.